# Mail_form : "No Route Matches [POST]" - Routing Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, contact-form, mail-form

**Rails 3.2**

I use the **Mail_form gem** (from plataformatec) to create a simple 'contact us' form for my website. When click on 'send' I get a routing error that says:

```
Routing Error
No route matches [POST] "/contactus"
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

I have a very simple setup, but I am new to Rails and am still getting the hang of it. I only want the form to send an email to a certain email address... nothing else. I understand the problem is in routes.rb but I have been fiddling with this for so long I just can't figure out what is wrong. I have never struggled with a Rails error so much. PLEASE HELP!

**'Pages' Model: app/models/pages.rb**

```
class Page < MailForm::Base
  attribute :name,          :validate => true
  attribute :email,         :validate => /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i
  attribute :page_title,    :validate => true
  attribute :page_body,     :validate => true

  def headers
    :subject => "#{page_title}",
    :to => "careers@example.com",
    :from => %("#{name}" <#{email}>)
  end
end
```

**'Pages' Controller: app/controllers/pages_controller.rb**

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :html

    def index
    end

    def create
        page = Page.new(params[:contact_form])
        if page.deliver
          redirect_to contactus_path, :notice => 'Email has been sent.'
        else
          redirect_to contactus_path, :notice => 'Email could not be sent.'
        end
    end
end
```

**Form Partial: app/views/pages/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for :contact_form, url: contactus_path, method: :post do |f| %>

<div>
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :email, label: 'Email address' %>
    <%= f.input :page_title, label: 'Title' %>
    <%= f.input :page_body, label: 'Your message', as: :text %>
</div>

<div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, label: 'Send', as: :text %>
</div>
```

**View (called contactus): app/views/pages/contactus.html.erb**

```
<body>
    <div>
        <h2 class="centeralign text-info">Contact Us</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="container centeralign">
            <%= render 'form' %>
    </div>
            <h2>We'd love to hear from you! </h2><br /><h4 class="muted">Send us a message and we'll get back to you as soon as possible</h4>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

**Routes.rb**

```
Example::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :pages
  root to: 'pages#index', as: :home
  get 'contactus', to: 'pages#contactus', as: :contactus
  get 'services', to: 'pages#services', as: :services
```

Comment: When you click on the 'send' button it is treated as a post request for which you don't have any route defined in routes.rb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your routes.rb file doesn't have a route for `POST /contactus`
You've got a route for `GET /contactus` but no `POST`, so what rails is saying is correct.

Just add something like

```
post 'contactus', to: 'controller#action'
```

With whatever controller and action you need to call. Alternatively, if you're trying to call the `create` action in the pages controller, then your problem is that where you've added `resources :pages` to routes, you've actually create the route

```
post 'pages'
```

So in that case, I'd change your `simple_form_for` url to post to there instead. Try using

```
simple_form_for :contact_form, url: pages_path, method: :post do
```

instead. If `pages_path` doesn't work, then just run `rake routes` in a console and you'll see a list of all of the routes you have including their names. Then just pick the one you need for this :)

Comment: Wow you answered in literally a minute. Thank you! I am getting an 'uninitialized constant' error in pagescontroller#create. Any ideas on why? I did create a 'Page' class in my Page.rb model...

Comment: Ah ok, that's down to the rails convention. In routes.rb you don't need to use the word `controller` as well. So change that to `pages#create` and it should be alright :)

Comment: That makes sense to me now! But it still says I have a naming error in pagescontroller#create ....

Comment: Even if you change that to `pages#create` instead of `pagescontroller#create`?

Comment: Yes... the error tells me its in the pages controller's 'create' method. But thats weird since I added post 'contactus', to: 'pages#create' in routes.rb

Comment: I dont know if this helps but it says the error is in line 8 of my Pages Controller. I believe it has to do with page= Page.new line?

Comment: OHHH ok sorry. OK so here again it's an issue with rails naming convention. Basically with rails, you never have to name things in a way that describes what they are. So in your case, you've called the file `page_model.rb`. Rails doesn't like this, so rename that to `page.rb`. The fact that it's in the models folder is enough for rails to know what it is :)

Comment: Umm Im so sorry this is embarassing but that was a typo on my part... its actually called pages.rb...

Comment: Ahh ok :P Not to worry. You'll probably want to make it singular as well, so `page.rb` instead of `pages.rb`. Rails can get pretty picky about its naming convention sadly

Comment: Hmm... now its telling me some this... thank you for being so patient with me I didn't realize I was this bad with RoR... :(  I updated the question with a picture of my error scary error message

Comment: That's alright not a problem. Rails is a little tricky to get used to as it's very picky about how it does things. Not seeing a picture?

Comment: Damn apparently I need 10 reputation points... LOL. This is such a fail. Heres my error: SYNTAX ERROR IN PAGESCONTROLLER#CREATE                C:/Sites/Logixity/app/models/page.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting keyword_end
    :subject => "#{page_title}"
               ^
C:/Sites/Logixity/app/models/page.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting keyword_end
    :to => "careers@logixity.com"
          ^
C:/Sites/Logixity/app/models/page.rb:11: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting keyword_end
    :from => %("#{name}" <#{email}>)
            ^

Comment: AHH ok that's pretty straight forward. You're just missing some curly braces in the `headers` method. You're trying to create a hash, but without the braces ruby doesn't know what you're trying to do. Just change it to `{ :subject => ........., }` and that should go away :)

Comment: Its still giving me that error. Currently I have                     def headers {
    :subject => "#{page_title}", 
    :to => "careers@logixity.com", 
    :from => %("#{name}" <#{email}>)}
  end

Comment: Well actually its saying unexpected '{', expecting ';' or '/n'

Comment: hm, have you put the opening `{` on the same line as the def? They need to be on different lines. The same with the closing `}` and the `end`

Comment: OH MY GOD THANK YOU IT FINALLY WORKS! Thank you!!! If theres any way I can possibly help you let me know!!!!

Comment: ha no problem glad it's working :) Just give me a shout if you run into any other problems